# How to decode json payload from raw bytes in a request?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to intercept a POST request made in a page and read its payload with `Content-Type: application/json`. However, the payload captured using `chrome.webRequest` is empty. I think this is because the json payload is in `raw` and I'm unable to parse it

background.js for sending a request to the content

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
            function(tabs) {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, details)
            })
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```

In the debugger the request looks like this -

```
request:
 frameId: 0
 initiator: "https://somewebsite.com"
 method: "POST"
 parentFrameId: -1
 requestBody:
  raw: Array(1)
   0:
    bytes: {}
requestId: "101041"
tabId: 597
timeStamp: 1554556743661.0898
type: "xmlhttprequest"
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve the JSON payload from the raw bytes?

Comment: `raw: Array(1)` raw is one byte - i.e., not likely to be JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't this is the case. According to the documentation `If the request method is PUT or POST, and the body is not already parsed in formData, then the unparsed request body elements are contained in this array.` raw being `Array(1)` indicates that there is one element and raw[0].bytes contains the arraybuffer of that element (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

Comment: Sounds like [Chrome webrequest doesn't see POST data in requestBody](//stackoverflow.com/a/33107811)

Comment: @wOxxOm I think it's a similar issue with parsing. But, it didn't work `String.fromCharCode.apply(null,new Uint8Array(request.requestBody.raw[0].bytes))` is itself returning an empty string. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Maybe it gets nuked automatically by the time chrome.tabs.query callback is executed, which you don't need by the way. Remove it and use request.tabId instead of tabs[0].id. It's also possible the encoding isn't UTF-16 so you need to actually examine the Uint8Array by setting a breakpoint in devtools debugger or logging it to console. Maybe you'll need to use TextDecoder API.

Comment: @wOxxOm It was actually getting nuked! Even after I changed it to request.tabId -- it wasn't working. I'm not sure why but the request's raw data gets cleared after I send it over a message to the content. As a workaround, I moved the parsing logic to the background and I'm sending the parsed raw data to the content from the background. Thanks a lot!